# Character wise sentence matching

Tags: c#, string

I have a string to compare with another set of string and need to get the score(percentage) of equality of these two (Ex: one to one same:100% and completely differs:0%). But the issue is those strings are consist with Japanese characters (Japanese sentences does not have spaces). How ever sometimes it consists some numerical characters (Ex: キロシカインスプレー　2mg ).

What would be the most appropriate way to perform this?

Comment: Would you want e.g. "This is a sentence" to match around 85% with "This is not a sentence" - or are you only interested in comparing "the character at index n with the character at index n in the other string", which makes my sample around a 30% match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese characters are still Unicode.

Use one of the standard string comparison algorithms like the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments, If you plan on factoring in equivalence of kanji to its hiragana, things are going to get complicated real fast. Before comparing, you may want to phoneticize the strings into, say, romaji or representative tokens.